# keep user logged in when offline in PWA using laravel auth

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, progressive-web-apps

I ran an application that to have access, the user needs to log in, this application has multi levels of authentication, this application is a PWA too.

The problem is that when the user downloads the APP to the home screen it always opens on the login screen, but as it can be offline it will not be able to log in.

How can I do to keep it logged in? that is, when the user is offline or online go directly to their dashboard.

I read some answers about sessions and cookies, is it really the best way?

No react or angular or vue was used.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: Actually I think the question is quite clear formulated but I don't have an answer unfortunately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took me a while to post the answer here, but it came.
Actually it was quite simple, just put in manifest.json to open the URL already logged in and solved my problem, of course it will only load if the user has ever accessed this URL according to my cache rules in the service worker, I suggest you try the same, if it doesn't work you can contact me that i can help.